# Arte - How to download rtmp or find the mp4 links

Tags: video

So I've found this, the XML page for the video I want to download
[Liveweb](http://download.liveweb.arte.tv/o21/liveweb/events/event-4985.xml)

and on that page there is this

```
rtmp://arte.fcod.llnwd.net/a2306/o25/MP4:liveweb/stream/5030_Deca_Dance_25fps_La_Batsheva_24_images_hd.mp4?e=1385247600&h=a6f3d498e98f267cb4318f30d48479a0
```

I thought I could stream/save this through VLC, but that doesn't work

Or I thought I might be able to see a direct mp4 link in there but cant seem to do this either

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Maybe the tatort-dl script can help you how to solve your problem!  http://rg42.org/wiki/tatort-dl

Comment: I was able to watch (nor download) rtmp via the gecko-mplayer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I use a python script based with rtmpdump command to download from Catalonian Television website (TV3).

This script fullfills the parameters of the command obtaining the data from the webpage where the video is posted, like this:

> ```
> rtmpdump -r rtmp://flash.dce.harvard.edu/bounce -C B:0 -C Z: \
> -C S:/2012/02/22872/L01/22872-20120124-L01-1-h264-av1248-16x9-852x480.mp4 \
> -C S:BounceAPI3.0 -C N:0.000000 -C S:mp4 \
> -y mp4:2012/02/22872/L01/22872-20120124-L01-1-h264-av1248-16x9-852x480.mp4 \
> -o a.flv
> RTMPDump v2.4-84-gdd57cd0
> (c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
> Connecting ...
> INFO: Connected...
> Starting download at: 0.000 kB
> [...]
> 3322.127 kB / 22.03 sec (0.3%)
> ```

*https://superuser.com/questions/528818/how-can-i-download-stream-videos-with-rtmp-protocol-from-harvard-extension-mor*